# “No resource found that matches the given name ... @style/Theme.AppCompat”

Tags: android

As far as I can tell (see picture below), my project is configured correctly because the support libraries are listen in "Referenced Libraries" - YET - the manifest is not allowing me to use `Theme.AppCompat`

At first I thought "Typical Eclipse! I'll do a project clean first", but that didn't resolve it.

What could be the problem ?

[image]

**Note1:** my project does have a /values/theme.xml which contains just the definition for "Theme.NoBackground". Would I need to add a "Theme.AppCompat" where the parent is "Theme.AppCompat" ??

**Note2:** this project does not have an application-wide theme. Only each activity has its own theme.

Comment: Have you tried doing this: Project root->right-click->Properties->Android->Go to the bottom and support-v7 **PROJECT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Import the support v7 appcompat from android sdk into eclipse by making a project

2) Right-click on **appcompat** project root, select properties, select android, scroll to the bottom and check "use as library" (or something similar to that)

3)Right-click on **your** project root, select properties, select android, scroll to the bottom and add the appcompat project as a library.

You're done!

Comment: That's exactly what I've done - I put all of my libraries inside a "ThirdParty" project... that project has the flag enabled "Is Library". Then I include that ThirdParty project inside my other projects. This approach has worked flawlessly since forever, but this v7 support library is being a .....

Comment: But observe step 3 properly. Click on **android** in the left-pane, scroll down then include the third-party project as a library

Comment: Yeah I did that too - and all the libraries within my ThirdParty/libs/ folder are used in my main project - Except - this v7 support library; the Theme.AppCompat still can't be resolved.

Comment: So I made some progress: your first step (to import the appcompat project from the SDK) actually made it possible for my project's manifest to resolve the Theme.AppCompat ! I wonder why the v7 support library requires its own project ?! Is there anything I can do to my "ThirdParty" library project that will make it work just as well ?

Comment: I don't know. I have been following the above method for 2-3 projects now

Comment: I've finally understood what's going on... the v7 library includes resources, hence, it must have its own project.

Comment: Correct @someonesomewhere